# Using the app delegate to start an iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate, application-design

I'm wondering if I should be relying less on my projects' App Delegate to setup my app - or should this sort of code belong to a singleton class part of the model?

For example -let's say, before my user gets to the first view - I need the app to download some data from a server and I need to preform a few checks and create a BaseDataStore type of class to store the stuff the app downloads. All this before my app starts.

Putting all this code in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions seems like the right thing to do - as this is what gets called once the app has launched. My question: Is this the right place to put it? Or do I create my own class for this sort of thing?

Comment: I'd suggest to have a VC that do the "wait" (downloading data) that go in your "normal" ViewController when done. In your AppDelegate, you just wonder if you already have the initial data and go to the "downloading VC" or the "normal" VC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: YES, you need to create your own classes.

To put all code in the AppDelegate and ViewController classes is a popular habit in iOS.
iOS apps tend to have small (auto-generated) model classes, which are then managed from the ViewControllers or the AppDelegate. Which is the fastest way to create a fart-app and the like.

In case you're building anything bigger then a fart-app, I suggest to take a different approach: A manager class could be in change of your model (setting it up, saving, etc). The AppDelegate then calls into the model manager when needed. Also, the application code generally improves when the "application logic" is placed in the model classes. To accomodate model changes (and regenerating the model classes), the auto-generated ManagedObjects should then be extended via categories containing your "application logic".

Comment: +1 -- keep your controller layer lean. use real separation

Comment: @Daij-Djan - Thanks guys - I'm starting a big iOS project and it's going to involve a lot of networking / XML parsing and Web Services. I need to do a few checks and create a few things before the user gets to the first screen - also need to download data and have it ready before then, too. So I wanted my code separated for each section. How do I go about - can I use App Delegates to just call methods from other classes to start instead then? Appreciate the feedback! P.S Where do I find out about the best way forward for ios app architecture best practices?

Answer (score 1):

For simple project loading data from network your process should be :

1. Create a custom LoadingViewController
2. Show it from the AppDelegate `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
3. Get the data with an entity manager
4. With a callback (delegate pattern should be nice) launch the first viewcontroller according to your data

The first 2 steps are for showing the app data is loading to the user (if you don't do that you'll have the Default.png showing a long time). If the first ViewController data can be refreshed you can directly load it, show cached data first and launch the refresh.

Comment: Well, when the app starts, I need to do something like this: 

1. Check is user has launched app before on this device
2. Preform actions based on the above (Login info, Agreement page, etc) 
3. Initilize a dataStore class
4. Download some data and parse it 
5. Carry on with the rest of the app start up.. 

I've looked at an old project done by another developer - all the start up stuff and checks are done in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions and that method is really large. Can I still use that method to call methods / start downloading stuff from other classes?

Comment: Yes the initial application flow can be written directly in the applicationDelegate but only the logic. if (user has launched) { call this controller; } else { call the other one; }. Then your controller can get the data through your a manager class.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help guys! I will do some more reading today on this subject.